# Answer "deleted" on thread and would like to get it undeleted

Tags: discussion, answers

This is the thread: [Does standing as opposed to sitting or lying improve brain activity?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20325/does-standing-as-opposed-to-sitting-or-lying-improve-brain-activity)

Here is the edited answer:
 0 down vote

> "Research suggests that walking may not make you a genius but it will improve >your attention and concentration not to mention help your mood, well being, >self-esteem, and even your physical health." It is well know that the one who >proved Fermat's Last Theorem took walks. It is also known that other >mathematicians and physicists took walks to think. this would seem to indicate >a benefit to walking. Erdos said "A mathematician is a machine that turns >coffee into theorems" and Erdos worked with so many people that the term >"Erdos number" was coined. Coffee is a stimulant as you know and thus it would >appear that walking/standing may indeed help. The quote is from: >http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/do-the-right-thing/201202/does-walking->make-you-smart-yes-and-in-more-ways-you-think

Is this adequate or do I need to further modify this?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of problems with this answer.

- It isn't well-known who proved Fermat's last theorem.
- It certainly isn't well known that he or she took walks. That needs a reference.
- Even then, that is still an anecdote, and is not evidence.
- If it is known that mathematicians and physicists take walks to think at a higher rate than the general population, that needs a reference.
- That does NOT indicate a benefit to walking. It is, at most, an unsubstantiated correlation.
- Erdos was not an expert on exercise and the brain. His opinion is irrelevant.
- That Erdos worked with many people is a non-sequitur.
- I don't believe it was Erdos who said that quote, but I could be convinced - it would need a reference.
- Coffee is irrelevant. Linking to walking from coffee is a non-sequitur.
- You have added the quote and a reference. That is certainly an improvement. However, the page you reference does not link to actual research, so it is little more than a repeat of the claim.

The question is whether, now that you've edited it, we should undelete the answer. It will certainly be downvoted heavily in its current state, and you will lose rep. Is that what you would like?

Comment: “It isn't well-known who proved Fermat's last theorem” – [???](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Wiles)

Comment: @Konrad: I studied Maths. I heard there had been a proof. I couldn't have told you the guy's name or even nationality. (And I STILL couldn't tell you if he liked going for walks.) What percentage of people need to know something before it is well-known? Whatever reasonable figure you give, fewer people know his name!